# script for terminal

Tags: macos, unix, terminal

I want to write a script that will connect to my server through my id (two layers of authentication) after i run the script.

```
ssh id@server->password
```

after this authentication one more authentication superuser authentication

```
username :

password :
```

My OS is MAC.

Comment: You should use RSA Key to login. Read on this: http://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/linux-generating-rsa-keys/

Comment: Login by RSA Key. For the second authentication, check Expect script.

Comment: Read this tutorial. http://bash.cyberciti.biz/security/expect-ssh-login-script/

Comment: @RomanNewaza it doesn't necessarily have to be a RSA key, DSA/ECDSA will work as well.

Comment: If you end up using `expect`, please remember that it will have security implications: either you store the root password in the script and you should therefore do your best to make the script unreadable for anyone except you, or you will be giving the password as command line argument in which case it might show clearly in the list of running processes (I'm not sure how MacOS handles this but on many UNICes this is the mode of operation).

Comment: @peterph, do you know the difference between them? Sure they will work!

Comment: @RomanNewaza different underlying crypto stack, c.f. [security SE](http://security.stackexchange.com/questions/5096/rsa-vs-dsa-for-ssh-authentication-keys).

Comment: @All can anyone tell me can i do it using simple unix scripting .if yes share the code plz.

Answer (score 0):

It's a lot tricker to get everything right so that this will "just work". The poorest documented problem is the correct protections on the login directory, the .ssh directory and the files in the .ssh directory. This is the script that I use to set everything up correctly:

```
#!/bin/tcsh -x
#
# sshkeygen.sh
#

# make sure your login directory has the right permissions
chmod 755 ~

# make sure your .ssh dir exists and has the right permissions
mkdir -pv -m 700 ~/.ssh
chmod 0700 ~/.ssh

# remove any existing rsa/dsa keys
rm -f ~/.ssh/id_rsa* ~/.ssh/id_dsa*

# if your ssh keys don't exist
set keyname = "`whoami`_at_`hostname`-id_rsa"
echo "keyname: $keyname"

if( ! -e ~/.ssh/$keyname ) then
    # generate them
    ssh-keygen -b 1024 -t rsa -f ~/.ssh/$keyname -P ''
endif

cd ~/.ssh

# set the permissions
chmod 0700 *id_rsa
chmod 0644 *id_rsa.pub

# create symbolic links to them for the (default) id_rsa files
ln -sf $keyname     id_rsa
ln -sf $keyname.pub id_rsa.pub
```

I have another script that copies the "`whoami`*at*`hostname`-id_rsa.pub" file onto a shared server (as admin) and then merges it into that systems .ssh/authorized_keys file which it then copies back onto the local machine. The first time these scripts run the user is prompted for the admin password to the shared server but after that everything will "just work".

Oh, and it's "Mac" (not "MAC"). [\pedantic] ;-)